# Angular Material showing two error messages

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using angular material and reactive form. I want when errors messages are showing, only one message show and if I solve one error show another.

How it is now:

[image]

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input matInput
         placeholder="Username"
         name="username"
         [formControlName]="'username'">
  <mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['username'].errors && form.controls['username'].touched">
    <div *ngIf="form.controls['username'].errors.required">
      Username is <strong>required</strong>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="form.controls['username'].errors.minlength">
      Required length: {{form.controls['username'].errors.minlength['requiredLength']}}
      Actual length:{{form.controls['username'].errors.minlength['actualLength']}}
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="form.controls['username'].errors.pattern">
      Only a-zA-Z0-9
    </div>

  </mat-error>

</mat-form-field>
```

Maybe I should use if else or something else? What do you think?

Comment: Did either of the answers help you?

Comment: Yes, both answers helped me, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can have one `<mat-error>` check if the control is `invalid` and then get your appropriate error message i.e.:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['username'].invalid">{{ getErrorMessage() }}</mat-error>
```

And then in your `.ts` you would have a function to retrieve the appropriate error message:

```
getErrorMessage() {
    return this.form.controls['username'].hasError('required') ? 'You must enter a value' :
        this.form.controls['username'].hasError('pattern') ? 'Not a valid username' :
        this.form.controls['username'].hasError('minlength') ? 'Required length is at least 3 characters' :
           '';
  }
```

You don't need those `divs`, the `<mat-error>` element should suffice if you have appropriate styles applied.

Here is a [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qdhrdh).

Comment: Brilliant :) This saves my day

Comment: calling a function `getErrorMessage()` in a template can be very dangerous. This function will be called for every change detection event.

Answer (score 7):

Was having the same problem.
This is what I came up with, simple and elegant.
No simultaneous `mat-error`'s will be shown when there are two or more.
Yet, the whole form will be invalid, disabling the submission.

```
mat-error + mat-error {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are almost there. To display different error messages one at a time, just check the other errors if they exist.

```
<mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['username'].errors && form.controls['username'].touched">
  <div *ngIf="form.controls['username'].errors.required &&
    !form.controls['username'].errors.pattern 
    && form.controls['username'].errors.minlength">
    Username is <strong>required</strong> //this is the first message error
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="form.controls['username'].errors.minlength &&
        !form.controls['username'].errors.required &&
        !form.controls['username'].errors.pattern"> // display error if required and pattern errors don't exist Required length: {{form.controls['username'].errors.minlength['requiredLength']}}
    Actual length:{{form.controls['username'].errors.minlength['actualLength']}}
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="form.controls['username'].errors.pattern &&
                     !form.controls['username'].errors.required &&
                     !form.controls['username'].errors.minlength
                 ">
    Only a-zA-Z0-9
  </div>
</mat-error>
```

Basically just negate `!` all the other error messages. This works for me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @sander the OP wanted to display multiple errors on a single field that's why there's  3 ngIfs. You can improve the code above by using If Else or Switch statement but it will only show one error at a time